# What percentage of missing datapoints is acceptable for a study?

Tags: missing-data

Let's say there are 300 cases that I want to analyze. I find out that I only have data for 278 of these cases. Thus, the analysis can only include approximately 93% of the sample instead of an ideal 100%. What is the extent of the conclusions that can be drawn in such a study?

In this situation, whether or not the data for a case is missing *seems* to be random. I.e., there is no variable that explains why the data is missing for these cases which could the created a bias that would affect any inference made (like a non response bias). Instead, there is no visible explanation for why this data is missing. Emphasis on "visible" because realistically, I guess you can't really be certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What percentage of missing datapoints is acceptable for a study?

There is no simple answer to this.

What you seem to be describing is a situation where the data are mising completely at random (MCAR). This is in contrast to other mechanisms such as missing at random (MAR) and missing not at random (MNAR)

When data are MCAR, complete case analysis leads to unbiased estimates, so with 93% complete cases you are safe to proceed with your analysis. However it is a good idea to verify MCAR using Little's MCAR test. Also, you will find an improvement in precision (lower standard errors) if you account for the missingness using multiple imputation - although with only 7% missingness this is likely to be a fairly modest improvement.

Little, R. J. A. 1988. A test of missing completely at random for multivariate data with missing values. Journal of the American Statistical Association 83: 1198–1202.
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1988.10478722